semaphore wait and post with fork
I need to create 5 processes, p2-p6 and have the output order to be p4, p3,p5,  p1, p6, p2 and for the life of me I can't understand why the sem_post doesn't cause the semaphore to stop waiting, but its likely I misunderstand something:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int main(){
    pid_t p2, p3, p4, p5, p6;
    sem_t sem_p1, sem_p2, sem_p3, sem_p4, sem_p5, sem_p6;
    sem_init(&sem_p1, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&sem_p2, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&sem_p3, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&sem_p4, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&sem_p5, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&sem_p6, 0, 0);

    p2 = fork();
    if(p2 < 0){
        perror("fork p1 -> p2 failed");
        return 1;   
    }
    if(p2 == 0){
        printf("hi");
        sem_wait(&sem_p2);
        printf("p2 output");
        return 0;
    }
    
    p3 = fork();
    if(p3 < 0){
        perror("fork p1 -> p3 failed");
        return 1;   
    }
    if(p3 == 0){
        sem_wait(&sem_p3);
        printf("p3 output");
        sem_post(&sem_p5);
        return 0;
    }

    p4 = fork();
    if(p4 < 0){
        perror("fork p1 -> p4 failed");
        return 1;   
    }
    if(p4 == 0){
        sem_wait(&sem_p4);
        printf("p4 output");
        sem_post(&sem_p3);
        return 0;
    }

    p5 = fork();
    if(p5 < 0){
        perror("fork p1 -> p5 failed");
        return 1;   
    }
    if(p5 == 0){
        sem_wait(&sem_p5);
        printf("p5 output");
        sem_post(&sem_p1);
        return 0;
    }

    p6 = fork();
    if(p6 < 0){
        perror("fork p1 -> p6 failed");
        return 1;   
    }
    if(p6 == 0){
        sem_wait(&sem_p6);
        printf("p6 output");
        sem_post(&sem_p2);
        return 0;
    }
    sem_post(&sem_p4);
    sem_wait(&sem_p1);
    printf("p1 output");
    sem_post(&sem_p6);
    return 0;


}


I was trying to get p4 output, p3 output, p5 output, p1 output, p6 output, p2 output

I don't receive any output so you may want to fflush(stdout) for your debug output to be shown or add some newlines to your strings.

When you fork a process, it makes a copy of the address space. But that doesn't mean that the objects in that address space are the same objects as in the parent process.
   p2 = fork();
    if(p2 < 0){
        perror("fork p1 -> p2 failed");
        return 1;   
    }
    if(p2 == 0){
        printf("hi");
        sem_wait(&sem_p2);
        printf("p2 output");
        return 0;
    }

When process p2 waits on sem_p2, it will wait forever because when process p6 posts to sem_p2, it is a different semaphore.
You can create semaphores that are shared between processes. The only way I've done it in the past is by first creating a shared memory segment with mmap(). Place the semaphore in that segment and initialize it with a '1' as the second parameter:
sem_init(&shared->semaphore, 1, 0);

Now when you do the fork, the child process will have access to the shared memory segment and will be able to use the shared semaphore.

Yes, sorry, I misread the man page.

To use semaphores as IPC, you need to use named semaphores, or POSIX Semaphores, instead of anonymous semaphores (process independent).
sem_init makes the semaphore available only to that process.
sem_open tie these to the fs, so that multiple processes can use the same semaphore(s).
Edit
For the "well, actually..." people: To create and use a semaphore without also needing to create and use shared memory, use named semaphores. Anonymous semaphores cannot be used for IPC without also including shared memory.

Not true. You can use anon semaphores.  But 1. They need to be allocated in shared memory, and 2. You need to use sem_init(sem, 1, init_val) instead of sem_init(sem, 0, init_val)

No, it is true. Both the shared memory and the anon semaphore need to be setup for shared access. To use just a semaphore across processes, without needing to also use shm, you have to use named semaphores.

That is not what you said. You said you couldn't use anonymous semaphores. This isn't true. You can use anonymous semaphores for IPC. /// Re "Both the shared memory and the anon semaphore need to be setup for shared access.", Yes, just like I said.
